# xuggler could not find input codec id (avi, msvideo1)

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, xuggle

I convert video from different formats to flv using xuggle MediaTool. For most of cases it works fine, but when I try an `.avi` file encoded with `msvideo1`, `indeo3` or `cinepark`, xuggler throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not find input codec id` on `reader.readPacket()`.

I checked, that my ffmpeg supports msvideo decoding:

```
 > ffmpeg -codecs
 (...)
 D V D  msvideo1        Microsoft Video 1
 D V D  indeo3          Intel Indeo 3
 D V D  cinepak         Cinepak
```

What is more, I'm able to convert files encoded with these codecs from the command line (usign ffmpeg).

What might be the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it was a problem with an outdated xuggler build. Current build (xuggler 3.4) is was published about 2 years ago and xuggler development advanced during that time.
The problem I was asking about was fixed after last release, [here is a ticket related to this problem](http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/issues/detail?id=252).
I built xuggler from source and it resolved this problem.

(Btw. finally I migrated to execution of `ffmpeg` because of pixel format problems.)